# Express the name of an element of vector in R by a variable's value?

Tags: r

For my problem of generic programming in R, I feel that it can be distiled as if it's possible to give name of an element of a vector through variable value.

For example,

```
y <- "interesting.value"
```

how can I in some form with y to express:

```
c("interesting.value" = 9)
```

It does not work with

```
c(y = 9)
```

this yields:

```
y 
9
```

I tried the following all didn't work.

```
c(as.name(y) = 9)

Error: unexpected '=' in "c(as.name(y) ="

c(as.symbol(y) = 9)

Error: unexpected '=' in "c(as.symbol(y) ="

c(as.quoted(y) = 9)

Error: unexpected '=' in "c(as.quoted(y) ="
```

Is there anyway to achieve this?

This is just an illustration. I want to learn how to parameterize on the name of value, or name of column, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this particular problem,

```
y <- "interesting.value"
setNames(c(9),y)
```

The usual suggestion of

```
eval(substitute(c(y=9),list(y="interesting.value")))
```

doesn't work here.

If you are planning to use `mutate()`, then the alternative form `mutate_` might be what you're looking for:

```
library("dplyr")
d <- data.frame(a=1)
y <- "all.zero"
mutate_(d,.dots=setNames(list(0),y))
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt help! I really wish some variation of eval(substitute(c(y=9),list(y="interesting.value"))) would work, as I actually need to parameterize on the symbol on the left hand side of assignment for data.frame's column name, such as y <- "all.zero", mutate(df, y=0)

Comment: Thanks again for giving me the pointer on mutate_, .dots, and setNames. It is exactly what I was searching for months! The link's explanation solved all my needs of  manipulation of variable column in a data.frame.

Answer (score 8):

```
y <- "interesting.value"
x <- 5
names(x) <- y
x
```

Produces:

```
interesting.value 
                5
```

You can also use `setNames`.

Comment: Your answer is perfect for my very question. I prefer the other answer, as I was trying to get a way to express generic way of parameterized on the identification of element name in vector or data.frame, when there are arbitrary number of elements.

Comment: @YuShen, no worries, though please note that this answer does work for an arbitrary numbers of parameters so long as `x` and `y` are the same length.